# Debug a Reactjs Application

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am going through the Reactjs doc and I tried adding a little feature to the tic-tac-toe game in the tutorial of the documentation. In the helper function that tells if a player won, there was no way to tell if the game ended as a draw. so I added this feature, however, there is a bug in my code, so that when the 9 squares are complete, and there is obviously a winner, sometimes it shows that there is a winner and sometimes it shows a draw. Please help to figure out this bug. Thank you.

```
function Square(props) {
    return (
      <button className="square" onClick={props.onClick}>
        {props.value}
      </button>
    );
  }

class Board extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      squares: Array(9).fill(null),
      xIsNext: true,
    }
  }
  handleClick(i){
    //console.log(this.state.counter)
    const squares = this.state.squares.slice();
    if(calculateWinner(squares) || squares[i]) {
      return;
    }
    squares[i] = this.state.xIsNext ? 'X' : 'O';
    this.setState({squares: squares, xIsNext: !this.state.xIsNext,})
    
  }
  renderSquare(i) {
    return <Square 
             value={this.state.squares[i]}
             onClick={()=>this.handleClick(i)}
           />;
  }

  render() {
    const winner = calculateWinner(this.state.squares);
    let status;
    if(winner) {
      status = 'Winner: ' + winner;
    } else {
      status = 'Next player: ' + (this.state.xIsNext ? 'X' : 'O');
    }

    return (
      <div>
        <div className="status">{status}</div>
        <div className="board-row">
          {this.renderSquare(0)}
          {this.renderSquare(1)}
          {this.renderSquare(2)}
        </div>
        <div className="board-row">
          {this.renderSquare(3)}
          {this.renderSquare(4)}
          {this.renderSquare(5)}
        </div>
        <div className="board-row">
          {this.renderSquare(6)}
          {this.renderSquare(7)}
          {this.renderSquare(8)}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Game extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="game">
        <div className="game-board">
          <Board />
        </div>
        <div className="game-info">
          <div>{/* status */}</div>
          <ol>{/* TODO */}</ol>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

// ========================================

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(<Game />);



function calculateWinner(squares, counter) {
    const lines = [
        [0, 1, 2],
        [3, 4, 5],
        [6, 7, 8],
        [0, 3, 6],
        [1, 4, 7],
        [2, 5, 8],
        [0, 4, 8],
        [2, 4, 6],
    ];
    for (let i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
        const [a, b, c] = lines[i];
    const squaresFilled = squares.every(value => value !== null);
    const threeSquaresEqual = squares[a] && squares[a] === squares[b] && squares[a] === squares[c]
    console.log(!threeSquaresEqual)
        if(threeSquaresEqual) {
            return squares[a];
        } else if(squaresFilled && threeSquaresEqual) {
            return "Draw";
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Are you getting any errors? If so, please provide them. Also, can you please explain what you have already done to try to fix the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of adding the logic at the winner just use a new **state** in the constructor to count the **turns** and evaluate if board has been completed without a winner

Add a new state to check on turns count

```
 constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      squares: Array(9).fill(null),
      xIsNext: true,
      turns: 0
    }
  }
```

Make the counter go up on the click event

```
  handleClick(i){
    //console.log(this.state.counter)
    const squares = this.state.squares.slice();
    if(calculateWinner(squares) || squares[i]) {
      return;
    }
    squares[i] = this.state.xIsNext ? 'X' : 'O';
    this.setState({
        squares: squares,
        xIsNext: !this.state.xIsNext,
        turns: this.state.turns + 1
    })    
  }
```

Then when rendering, if turns are 9 and winner is null then render "Draw"

```
render() {
    const winner = calculateWinner(this.state.squares);
    let status;
    if(winner == null && turns == 9) {
      status = 'Draw'; 
    } else if(winner) {
      status = 'Winner: ' + winner;
    } else {
      status = 'Next player: ' + (this.state.xIsNext ? 'X' : 'O');
    }

    return (<> ... </>)
}
```

Something like that.

Comment: Notice that the calculateWinner function will return either null or a string, so returning "Draw" means somebody actually won, this might be why you still get a winner rendered even there was a draw

Comment: Wow! I never thought of this. I have not implanted it but I'm sure it will work. Thank you very much Rodrigo.

Comment: Actually, it returns a draw when it is a draw, the problem was that it returns a draw when there is an actual winner.

Comment: Sorry, I meant, it should return the winner itself either "X" or "O" and null means there is no winner